# Каково значение суффикса -иц в слове "страница"?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, суффиксы

Страница, по-видимому,  мотивируется существительным "сторона" и образуется с помощью суффикса-иц.

Для сравнения: существительные странник/странница и сторонник/сторонница образуются от существительных "страна" и "сторона" с помощью суффикса  -ниц.

Какое значение имеет суффикс -иц в слове "страница" и когда это слово появилось в языке?

Ответ на этот вопрос позволяет объяснить разное написание слов: страница - странница.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну не нашла я суффикса *-иц-* как класса.

[Происхождение](https://obrazovaka.ru/koren-slova/stranica.html)

> Слово «страница» имеет старославянское происхождение. Оно родственно
>   общеславянскому «сторона». Дословное толкование «страницы» —
>   «маленькая сторона». Так называли раньше и называют до сих пор
>   поверхность писчей бумаги (одну из двух).

Основа слова: СТРАНИЦ.

Способ образования: бессуфиксный.

---

Иное дело *странница* - исторически однокоренная, сейчас уже нет!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[История происхождения слова «страница»](http://textexpert.ru/kak-napisat-slovo-stranicy/)**

> Праславянское слово «storna» на кириллице стало выглядеть как
>   «сторона». В таком виде слово как одна из веток словообразования дошло
>   до нас, одно из его значений было (и сейчас есть) – поверхность
>   какого-то предмета. Немного изменившись, слово появилось в виде
>   «страна» в русском, болгарском, украинском и ещё нескольких языках.
>
> По идее, в слове «страница» должен быть корень «стран-», раз
>   прародители его – «сторона/страна». ***По современным правилам корень
>   — «страниц-», так как слово образовано при сращивании корня и
>   суффикса.***

Нотабене!

> Ещё один пример такого слова – «станица», в котором корень «станиц-»,
>   несмотря на то, что есть слово-родственник «стан».
>
> Интересно то, что такое словообразование произошло только в русском
>   языке.
>
> ---
>
> (Слово «странный» нельзя обойти вниманием из-за его первоначального
>   значения. Устаревший и уже не употребляемый его смысл – скитающийся по
>   чужой земле.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я предварительно пыталась найти ответ сама и видела статью о происхождении слова. Но дело в том, что источник информации неясен. Как ни странно, авторитетные словари не рассматривают этимологию этого слова. Даже в словаре П.Я. Черных (историко-этимологическом) нет сведений о происхождении и времени появления в языке. У него есть статья о слове "сторона", в ней указано, что в ряде славянских языков сторона и страница обозначались одним словом (например: strana чеш.) - сторона и страница).

Comment: В русском языке суфффикс ИЦ может иметь уменьшительное значение (кожа - кожица) или единичное (крупа - крупица). Что выбрать: страница - это маленькая сторона или часть стороны? И когда образовалось слово (с учетом  неполногласие РА)? Его надо считать исконным или заимствованным?

Comment: Нашла наконец всевозможные объяснения *-иц-*: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%B8%D1%86 и http://project.karelia.ru/atlant/help/suf_ref.htm - я не знаю, какое "наше"! На вопрос "когда?" наука ответа не даёт; в исконности же у меня сомнений нет.